# Load Testing - Socket Connection Aborted While Running The Load Test

Tags: testing, load

I am running a load test in order to see the performance of the WCF services during the peak time (heavy load). I am using the Step-Load where we push the virtual users Step-by-Step. When I start running the load test for the first few minutes the test runs smoothly and as the load increases by time, after some time all of a sudden the below error is triggering,

"Test method "XYZ" threw exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".
```

I tried lot of solution that I found online but non of them worked for me. I tried changing the default time-outs, maxconnections, maxconcurrent connections etc., in config files. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems while ago when moved to WCF. It have probably something to do with the way WCF handles connections.

Solution for me was to move each test into separate ApplicationDomain.